# No package matching atomic-openshift-utils

Tags: ansible, openshift

Im trying to install atomic-openshift-utils package using yum module in ansible.When running it I'm getting error

```
- name: atomic-openshift-utils
      yum:
        name: "{{packages}}"
      vars:
        packages:
         - atomic-openshift-utils
```

````
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'atomic-openshift-utils' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'atomic-openshift-utils' found available, installed or updated"]}```
````

Comment: Did you add the required repos?

Comment: can you please tell what are the repos required for it?

Comment: I did **yum reposlist all** it is showing me some list .... how would I know which one is essential for the atomic-openshift-utils package?

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: $ `subscription-manager repos --enable="rhel-7-server-rpms" --enable="rhel-7-server-extras-rpms" --enable="rhel-7-server-ose-3.7-rpms" --enable="rhel-7-fast-datapath-rpms"`

$ `yum -y update`

Comment: RHEL 7.6 ... when Im installing it directly on machine ,atomic-openshift-utils installs successfully... it is not working in ansible scripts

Comment: How did you install it in the machine? just yum install package or yum install http://url_to_rpm?

Comment: Im doing yum install package

Comment: getting error when enabling repos "Error: 'rhel-7-server-ose-3.7-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID

Comment: same for rhel-7-fast-datapath-rpms ... checked subscription-manager repos --list there are no repos of that name

Comment: Im using Openshift 3.9

Answer (score 0):

#### Try installing dep repo packages and then the actual package

```
- name: install deps
  yum:
    name: "{{packages}}"
  vars:
    packages:
     - centos-release-openshift-origin39
     - centos-release-paas-common

- name: install atomic-openshift-utils
  yum:
    name: atomic-openshift-utils
```

Comment: I tried that getting error ```FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'atomic-openshift-utils' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'atomic-openshift-utils' found available, installed or updated"]}```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'centos-release-openshift-origin39' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'centos-release-openshift-origin39' found available, installed or updated"]}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the corresponding subscriptions enabled, you might need to extend your definition a bit for this.

If we take a look at the actual docs here https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/install/prerequisites.html , we see that we need to enable some subscriptions in order to add the repos to be queried.

What that will looks like in ansible:

```
- name: Enable all repositories starting with rhel-7-server-*
  rhsm_repository:
    name: rhel-7-server-*
    state: enabled
```

After that you should be fine with your definition. So in total you'll have something like this:

```
- name: Enable all repositories starting with rhel-7-server-*
  rhsm_repository:
    name: rhel-7-server-*
    state: enabled
- name: atomic-openshift-utils
  yum:
    name: "{{packages}}"
  vars:
    packages:
    - atomic-openshift-utils
```

Please note that using a wildcard on the repos might give you a lot more than you need. You have adjust that to your needs.